# How do I restart sshd on raspbian?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, services, openssh

How do I restart sshd on raspbian stretch?

This does not work:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/.ssh $ sudo systemctl restart sshd
Failed to restart sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found.
```

Comment: try this sudo systemctl restart ssh instead no d

Comment: Why did they drop the d? Its sshd on my Debian stretch.

Comment: On my Debian stretch I have ssh.service and sshd.service pointing both to `/usr/sbin/sshd -D`.

Comment: Can you please accept one answer, so your question is finished and will not pop up again for years?

Answer (score 9):

Same issue with both stretch and jessie. Until you enable the service with:

```
systemctl enable ssh
```

you cannot refer to the service as "sshd".  Once the service is enabled, no problem, you can even disable the service with:

```
systemctl disable sshd
```

Really stupid in my opinion but that's the way it is.

Comment: Exactly, I'm installing ArchlinuxArm to get rid of this kind of hassles.

Comment: @wuxb: You can run, but you cannot hide :)  The `ssh` vs `sshd` thing is a **deliberate decision** by the folks who bring you `systemd`.  LOL

Answer (score 5):

In my case on raspberry pi 3B+ device with raspbian OS work this:

```
sudo service ssh status
sudo service ssh restart
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments the main service is `ssh.service`. But you can it also address with `sshd.service`. As you can see `ssh.service` has an Alias:

```
pi ~$ systemctl cat ssh
# /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service
[..]
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
pi ~$
```

Quoted from `man systemd.unit`:

> In addition, unit files may specify aliases through the Alias=
>   directive in the [Install] section; those aliases are only effective
>   when the unit is enabled.

With

```
pi ~$ sudo systemctl enable ssh
```

You can also get it with:

```
pi ~$ systemctl status sshd
```